# What is the correct way to check the test coverage of an android library?

Tags: android, project, code-coverage, emma

My main project is an android library.
I have created a test project with some unit test in it.
the tests run fine, but I am struggling to get the test coverage.
When I generate the coverage report, I only get the coverage of the tests cases,
but not of the library.
So it gives me almost 100% because 100% of the test are running.
but that doesn't help me to tell what part of the library has been tested.

This is how I do it at the moment :

```
0) my project looks like this:
myLibraryProject        <- this is my android library project
myLibraryProject/tests  <- this is my android test project

1) build.xml file : (from myLibraryProject/tests directory)
>android update test-project --path . -m ../

2) Modify the ant.properties file :
#tested.project.dir=../
android.library.reference.1=..

3) only then can I run :
ant emma debug install test
```

if I don't do step 2) then step 3) fails because the library project can not be installed

Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution I found:

Create a new build.xml in your test project
copy the "test" target from android sdk build.xml file (I have used sdk20 preview 2 version)

modify the sourcepath to point at the library project in the report section

this is the one I use now :

```
 <!-- version-tag: custom -->
 <target name="test" depends="-test-project-check"
            description="Runs tests from the package defined in test.package property">
    <property name="test.runner" value="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />

    <if condition="${project.is.test}">
    <then>
        <property name="tested.project.absolute.dir" location="${tested.project.dir}" />

        <!-- Application package of the tested project extracted from its manifest file -->
        <xpath input="${tested.project.absolute.dir}/AndroidManifest.xml"
                expression="/manifest/@package" output="tested.project.app.package" />
    </then>
    <else>
        <!-- this is a test app, the tested package is the app's own package -->
        <property name="tested.project.app.package" value="${project.app.package}" />
    </else>
    </if>

    <property name="emma.dump.file" value="/data/data/${tested.project.app.package}/coverage.ec" /> 

    <if condition="${emma.enabled}">
        <then>
            <echo>WARNING: Code Coverage is currently only supported on the emulator and rooted devices.</echo>
            <run-tests-helper emma.enabled="true">
                <extra-instrument-args>
                    <arg value="-e" />
                       <arg value="coverageFile" />
                       <arg value="${emma.dump.file}" />
                </extra-instrument-args>
            </run-tests-helper>
            <echo level="info">Downloading coverage file into project directory...</echo>
            <exec executable="${adb}" failonerror="true">
                <arg line="${adb.device.arg}" />
                <arg value="pull" />
                <arg value="${emma.dump.file}" />
                <arg value="coverage.ec" />
            </exec>
            <echo level="info">Extracting coverage report...</echo>
            <emma>
                <report sourcepath="../${source.dir}" verbosity="${verbosity}">
                    <sourcepath>
                      <dirset dir="${basedir}" >
                        <include name="../src" /> 
                        </dirset>
                    </sourcepath>
                    <infileset dir=".">
                        <include name="coverage.ec" />
                        <include name="coverage.em" />
                    </infileset>
                    <html outfile="coverage.html" />
                    <xml outfile="coverage/coverage.xml" />
               </report>
            </emma>
            <echo level="info">Cleaning up temporary files...</echo>
            <delete file="coverage.ec" />
            <delete file="coverage.em" />
            <echo level="info">Saving the report file in ${basedir}/coverage/coverage.html and ${basedir}/coverage/coverage.xml</echo>
        </then>
        <else>
            <run-tests-helper />
        </else>
    </if>
</target>
```